# How to show a caret immediately after a Prosemirror editor is turned editable?

Tags: javascript, prose-mirror

I have a use-case where the ProseMirror editor is not editable at first (readonly mode). Once the user double-clicks the editor, the editor becomes editable.

```js
/**
 * The schema is defined to have paragraphs within a document.
 */

const state = EditorState.create({
  schema,
  doc: schema.nodeFromJSON(emptyDoc),
});

const view = new EditorView(document.getElementById('editor'), {
  state,
  editable: () => false,
});


/**
 * Once the user double clicks the editor, we enable it to be editable.
 */
view.setProps({
  editable: () => true,
});
```

This all works fine. The issue here is that the caret is not visible immediately when it turns editable. Of course, I can click on the text and it becomes visible.

But, I want it to be shown immediately at the position where it was double clicked. Is this possible?

Comment: Were you able to solve this question?